# How to upgrade my python3.7.4 in kalli linux

Tags: python, kali-linux, python3

I have two python versions in my machine **python2.7** and **python3.7.4**. How can I upgrade my **python3.7.4** to **python3.8** and set its as default across all user?

Comment: Have you at some point installed it with your `apt` package manager? Does your package repositories provide a newer version?

Comment: @panki Agreed that Kali Linux isn't suitable for desktop use or beginners in general, but this isn't the place or time to rehash that discussion. Besides, it's easier to talk sense into someone if the first words out of your mouth aren't a derisive insult.

Comment: @Shadur you are right, but Kali creates so many low quality questions which are pretty much unsalvagable without first giving the OP a complete basic introductory course on Linux.

Comment: @Panki Everybody need to start learning something at some instance, instead of going beyond the topic, please kindly answer my question :D

Comment: And installing Kali to the desktop is a *terrible* way to start learning. I'm actually agreeing with @Panki here, I'm just more polite about it.

Comment: @ChinkySight Please take a look at [Kali Linux' own recommendations on this exact subject](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux).

Comment: @ChinkySight Sure, but one does not learn to drive in a F1 car in a circuit.

Comment: @dr01 I am taking a course from udemy on that :D, but this topic is bugging me so that I thought better ask someone for the answer

Comment: I found a solution to do it locally :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to be blunt here:

**Don't**.

The reason python 2.7 is still installed on your system is *almost certainly* because various scripts and programs, possibly system-essential ones, still rely on 2.7 and haven't been ported to 3.x yet.

**Python 2.7 programs *do not work* in Python3 without extreme rewriting. Your package manager will almost certainly refuse to let you delete 2.7, and you risk breaking your entire system if you try to force it.**

I'm not terribly familiar with Kali specifically (and this is neither the time or place to once more point out that Kali isn't intended to be, and [shouldn't be used](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux) as, a general-purpose desktop system), but I do know that Debian maintainers are working hard to audit all their software to make sure there'll be no more remaining 2.7-reliant scripts well before the sunset.

Also, to ease your fears a bit, Jan 1st 2020 is when the official Python team will stop supporting and maintaining 2.7; most distributions have their own maintenance teams that generally can and will address security issues as they arise for at least long enough for their own software to no longer be dependent on 2.7.